# transformations using XSLT/XQUERY in MarkLogic?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, marklogic

Sample XML:

```
let $xml := document {
  <doc>
    <p>sample</p>
    <categories>
      <category>comdey</category>
      <category>drama</category>
    </categories>
  </doc>
}
```

Code:

```
let $xsl :=
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="category">
      <entertainment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </entertainment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="categories">
      <entertainments>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </entertainments>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>

return xdmp:xslt-eval($xsl, $xml)
```

The above code can be executed from MarkLogic Query Console and it will replace "categories" with "entertainments" and "category" with "entertainment".

But how do we write this as a MarkLogic xslt transform that can be installed and applied using REST API or Java API to an xml file saved in MarkLogic.

Read this:
The creation and installation of transforms through JAVA API is already implemented and is working for the sample content transformation files given in MarkLogic site.

The problem is we are not clear on how to convert this xslt code to a transform dialect as specified by MarkLogic. We did try to convert but are getting the error(mentioned at bottom)

trail.xslt Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:example="http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/trial"
    xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map">
  <xsl:param name="context" as="map:map"/>
  <xsl:param name="params"  as="map:map"/>
  <xsl:template match="genre">
    <entertainment>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </entertainment>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="genres">
    <entertainments>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </entertainments>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We have saved the above code as trail.xslt and tried to install the transform but facing some errors and the error is as follows

Error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: config/transforms write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000)


Invalid content: invalid trial extension: could not parse XQuery extension trial; please see the server error log for detail XDMP-IMPORTMOD: Cannot import Main Module /marklogic.rest.transform/trial/assets/transform.xqy; trial either is not a valid module or does not provide extension functions (transform) in the http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/trial namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

To put it short, you need to do a PUT call to /v1/config/transforms/yourtransformname against your REST-api server with the XSLT as request body. Details are described here:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/transforms/[name]

One important bit of that is, when you push an XSLT, make sure to prove the following header, otherwise it could assume it is XQuery, like your error message is assuming:

```
Content-type: application/xslt+xml
```

Once there you can apply the transform to /v1/documents (GET, POST and PUT), as well as to /v1/search GET response by adding a transform request param with value yourtransformname. Details here:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/documents
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/documents
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/documents@extension=[ext]
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/search
- (and maybe more..)

The api reference documentation contains lots of deep links into user guides. Those are usually worth reading too.

HTH!

Comment: we have updated the question. The installation of transforms through JAVA API is already implemented and is working for the sample content transformation files given in Marklogic site. Its throwing some errors as mentioned in question.

Comment: I updated the answer. The message seems to indicate it was installed incorrectly. Might also help to provide the code or command with which it was installed..

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it looks like the install is writing the transform with the *.xqy message, which means the installer is trying to parse the transform as XQuery.

Is it possible that you are writing the transform with the writeXQueryTransform() method?

If so, try with the writeXSLTransform() method:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/admin/TransformExtensionsManager.html#writeXSLTransform%28java.lang.String,%20com.marklogic.client.io.marker.XMLWriteHandle%29

Hoping that helps.